# Pyspark filter empty lines from RDD not working

Tags: python, lambda, filter, pyspark, rdd

I'm relatively new to spark and pyspark

```
final_plogfiles = plogfiles.filter(lambda x: len(x)>0)
```

I wrote this code to filter out the empty lines from the RDD plogfiles. It did not remove the empty lines.

I also tried

```
plogfiles.filter(lambda x: len(x.split())>0)
```

But if I use `plogfiles.filter(lambda x: x.split())`, trailing, and leading white spaces in all lines are getting trimmed

I only want to filter out empty lines. I would like to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I used rstrip() that is getting me the results. I would still be interested to know the answer because it might help me with other things! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is plogfiles an RDD?
following works fine for me:

```
lines = sc.textFile(input_file)
non_empty_lines = lines.filter(lambda x: len(x)>0 )
```